# Trigger my app when another app closed

Tags: android, triggers, launch

I launch another app from my application.

Is there any way to trigger my app when launched app closed?!

Is it good idea to use timer and check package name ?!

Answer (score 1):

Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result, call `startActivityForResult()` (instead of `startActivity()`).

**For example, your app can start a camera app and receive the captured photo as a result. Or, you might start the People app in order for the user to select a contact and you'll receive the contact details as a result.**

Of course, the activity that responds must be designed to return a result. When it does, it sends the result as another Intent object. Your activity receives it in the `onActivityResult()` callback.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you launch the app with startActivityForResult, you will end up in onActivityResult in your application when it closes, that is the normal flow.

But if you want to always launch your app when the other closes, it can be done using a service, but I wouldn't recommend doing that since it's bad practise.

Comment: If app does not return any result can I use `onActivityResult` to find out app closed?!

Comment: Yes, you will get RESULT_CANCELED and the data Intent will be null.